# How can I get the rotatation with fcurves.find()?

Tags: python, fcurves

What I want is a way to take the rotation fcurves with the code fcurves.find(), is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

From blender 2.76 we can use [`fcurves.find(data_path, index)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.find) to get specific fcurves for an object. The fcurves for rotation data may be stored under several different `data_path` values depending on what [`rotation_mode`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode) was enabled when the keyframes were added.

Of the eight possible values for `rotation_mode` three different `data_path` values are used, one is `rotation_quaternion`, one is `rotation_axis_angle` and the other is `rotation_euler` that is used by all six permutations of `XYZ` used for euler rotation modes.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
obj_fcurves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves

if obj.rotation_mode == 'QUATERNION':
    w_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_quaternion', index=0)
    x_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_quaternion', index=1)
    y_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_quaternion', index=2)
    z_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_quaternion', index=3)
elif obj.rotation_mode == 'AXIS_ANGLE':
    w_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_axis_angle', index=0)
    x_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_axis_angle', index=1)
    y_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_axis_angle', index=2)
    z_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_axis_angle', index=3)
else:
    x_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_euler', index=0)
    y_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_euler', index=1)
    z_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_euler', index=2)
```

For versions before 2.76 `fcurves.find()` is a generic find that doesn't work as expected, in this case you need to loop through the curves to find the one you want.

```
for c in obj_fcurves:
    if c.data_path == 'rotation_quaternion':
        if c.array_index == 0:
            w_fcurve = c
        elif c.array_index == 1:
            x_fcurve = c
        elif c.array_index == 2:
            y_fcurve = c
        elif c.array_index == 3:
            z_fcurve = c
```